# Formatting code nicely

Tags: matlab

Extremely simple question:
how can I format my code to be nicely readable. Example:

```
A = (B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K...)
```

and let's say it is so long that I have to scroll for ages to later see what I wrote.
If however I press enter to separate the line like this:

```
A = (B+C+D+E
+F+G+H+I...)
```

matlab reports error

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `...` at the line break. [It is a line continuation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f0-5789.html#f0-5857).

Answer (score 6):

Use `...` to split lines:

Instead of `a = x + y + z`, you can use:

```
a = x ...
+ y...
+ z
```

Comment: Merci, Danke, Grazias, Hvala!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for "line continuation".

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f0-5789.html#f0-5857

Comment: Merci, Danke, Grazias, Hvala!